# Config swiftshader mode for emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, apple-m1

I have a UI display problem on emulator only and some people say that it can be fixed by using swiftshader for emulator (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/10829)

I already tried to update the `config.ini` file to

```
hw.gpu.enabled = yes
hw.gpu.mode = swiftshader_indirect
```

but the emulator can not launch anymore, if it is `hw.gpu.mode = auto`, emulator will work fine.

I also tried to enable SwiftShader in GUI (Emulator -> 3 dots -> Settings - Advanced)

[image]

After that, all of my emulators can not launch. And I can't find anyway to revert this setting, so I need to reinstall AS.
I'm using Mac M1, Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Beta 5.
Is there anyway to enable swiftshader successfully?